# How to check '+' in permissions of file? (ACL)

Tags: c, macos, file, permissions, acl

I need to display the permissions of file in C. But I don't know how to print out '+' if the file has ACL.

I have tried to use the `acl_get_file` function but it always returns NULL even if the file has ACL.

```
acl_t acl;
acl = acl_get_file("Users/mavramenko/Desktop/ucode/file.txt", ACL_TYPE_ACCESS);
if (acl != NULL)
    printf("+");
```

Comment: Whic OS are you using?

Comment: @Jabberwocky, macos

Comment: Have you checked the value of errno ? Maybe NULL is returned because acl_get_file() fails.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists at that location? Where is your working directory and where is the file you want to read? Maybe you wanted to use an absolute path?

Comment: @MaximeEychenne, yes. Invalid argument is printed by errno.

Comment: @Gerhardh, yeah, exactly

Comment: Then it works if you fix the path?

Comment: @Gerhardh, no. Invalid argument is printed

Comment: Maybe you could show us how you fixed your wrong path?

Comment: BTW: I asked 4 questions in my first comment. There are a few open after your "yeah, exactly" answer.

Comment: @Gerhardh, if file doesn't exists then error file not found will be printed. So error invalid argument exactly not in file existance

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is to use the type `ACL_TYPE_ACCESS`. That's what's causing the error.

The solution is to use the type `ACL_TYPE_EXTENDED` instead.

This can also be learned from reading the header file `<sys/acl.h>`:

```
typedef enum {
    ACL_TYPE_EXTENDED   = 0x00000100,
/* Posix 1003.1e types - not supported */
    ACL_TYPE_ACCESS         = 0x00000000,
    ACL_TYPE_DEFAULT        = 0x00000001,
```

For the record, here's sample code for getting the ACL of a file:

```
const char *path = "/path/to/file";
acl_t acl = acl_get_link_np (path, ACL_TYPE_EXTENDED);
if (acl == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"%s – Error: %s", path, strerror(errno));
} else {
    const char *desc = acl_to_text (acl, NULL);
    NSLog(@"%s: %s", path, desc);
    acl_free ((void*)desc);
}
acl_free (acl);
```